# DNS not resolving on Virtualmin

Tags: domain-name-system

I am having problems reaching my site hosted on a virtualmin virtual server. It is the only site I have hosted on the server right now (I am just learning my way around virtualmin and VPSs in general) and I can access it via IP address but not via the domain name.
Running `whois` returned the correct nameservers so I then ran:

```
host mysite.com ns1.mynameserver.com
```

and received "connection timed out; no servers could be reached."

I then added my ip address manually to named.conf and ran:

```
host mysite.com ns1.mynameserver.com
```

again, which now yields the correct IP.

The only problem is my site is still unreachable via the domain name (I get "server not found"). I setup all the DNS stuff more than 24hrs ago with the exception of adding my IP to the named.conf file.

My question is, shouldn't my domain name resolve to the site now that `host mysite.com ns1.mynameserver.com` returns the correct IP?
Any idea as to what I should do next?

Also, why did I have to add my IP manually to named.conf? Did I miss something in the virtualmin setup or (more likely) screw up some setting that I am not aware of?

I did set virtualmin to listen locally only so as to access it via an ssh tunnel, could this have lead to an alteration of the named.conf file?

I appreciate any assistance and beg your indulgence of a rank amateur. I am sure this is just the first of many stupid questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mathias, you made the question much more readable. I should have formatted the question a bit differently when I wrote it, suppose I was just in a hurry due to being frustrated and over-caffeinated.

Answer (score 1):

So after taking a break and coming back to the problem and a little help from the virtualmin forums this is why the nameservers were not responding:

The name.conf file was completely set up for local use only. I was under the impression that virtualmin was supposed to take care of this but as I said before I am very new at this. When I added the IP manually to named.conf I should have also changed:

```
allow-query { localhost; };
```

to

```
allow-query { any; };
```

Hopefully this will be of some use to those who encounter a similar situation.